# Running wine without displaying the GUI window

Tags: command-line, wine

I would like to run

```
wine myapp.exe
```

without displaying the GUI window.

`myapp.exe` is a command-line application.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is.
Use the `/nogui` switch, i.e.:

```
wine "myapp.exe /nogui"
```

---

If this doesn't work, you may be able to get it working by installing [gdiplus extension for WINE](http://wiki.winehq.org/GdiPlus).

Comment: With the `/nogui` switch, it still displays the GUI window. I looked at the link with `gdiplus`, but there are no instructions, how to install it.

Comment: I installed it according to this website [this](http://ubuntu-snippets.blogspot.cz/2008/05/as-most-of-us-know-wine-is-used-to-run.html), but it still shows GUI.

Comment: you may want to take a look at: https://www.winehq.org/site/docs/wineusr-guide/config-wine-main, specifically 4.1.3. Graphics Settings

Comment: I unchecked `emulate a virtual desktop` and it works even without `/nogui` switch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the gui to a virtual display server like [`xvfb`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) to hide the GUI window.

[`Xvfb is an X server that can run on machines with no display hardware and no physical input devices. It emulates a dumb framebuffer using virtual memory.`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml)

So, you can do the following:

Install `xvfb` and possible dependencies:

```bash
sudo apt install xorg xvfb xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
```

Then, use `wine` with `xvfb-run`:

```bash
xvfb-run wine myapp.exe
```

For using just `wine` command to do it, you can use alias:

```bash
alias wine='xvfb-run wine'
```

However aliases could not work in subprocesses, to make it permanent, you can create a script that named `wine` in your `/usr/local/bin` directory like this (`/usr/bin/wine` is your actual `wine` binary):

```bash
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo nano wine
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
xvfb-run /usr/bin/wine "$@"
```

Then make the script executable:

```bash
sudo chmod +x wine
```

After this, every `wine` command will be executed with `xvfb-run` prefix and that means every `wine` will work without gui.